# Is the reciprocal of this Kummer theorem true?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Le p be an odd prime, let $\zeta$ be a primitive p-th root of unity, let K denote the p-th cyclotomic field. Let us define a singular element of K as an integral element $\alpha$ of K, not divisible by $1 - \zeta$, such that the ideal $(\alpha)$ is the p-th power of an ideal of K. Let i be a natural number such that $1 \leq i \leq (p-3)/2$. Kummer proved that if (the numerator of) the 2i-th Bernoulli number $B_{2i}$ is not divisible by p, then, for every singular number $\alpha$, 
$l^{p-2i}(\alpha) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$,
where $l$ denotes the Kummer logarithmic function.

Is it true that if $B_{2i}$ is divisible by p, there exists a singular element $\alpha$such that $l^{p-2i}(\alpha)$ is not 0 modulo p ?

Comment: Isn't this Ribet's converse to Herbrand's theorem?